# No console.log output in firebase console for cloud functions written in Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I was using Typescript to write some Firebase cloud functions like below:

*index.ts*

```
export * from "./Module1";
```

*Module1.ts*

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const test = functions.https.onRequest(
  (request, response) => {
     console.log("Hello");
  }
);
```

And then use `firebase deploy` to compile the code into Javascript and upload them. The whole deploy process ran with no error. But the compiled *Module1.js* in `lib` directory do not have the `console.log()` line:

*Module1.js*

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
}
```

Then I checked in my firebase console, there was no log output for the line `console.log("Hello");`. I guess `tsc` may striped off `console.log()`, but it is just a guess. I still do not know why this happened. My *tsconfig.json* is as follow:

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: I tested your example and the "hello" showed up for me. Your function will timeout because there is no `res.send()` at the end, but that shouldn't cause this issue. What version of the Firebase CLI and Cloud Functions are you using?

Comment: I'm using firebase 6.5.0 and firebase functions 2.2.0. Will Typescript tsc compilation keep the ```console.log()``` line or use other mechanisms to separate log function?

Comment: Hi Jen, I found the problem... Silly me. In my code, I wrote the ```console.log("Hello")``` into another file Module2.ts... Thanks for the time and sorry for the inconvenience...

Answer (score 1):

Silly me. In my local code, I wrote the `console.log("Hello")` into another file Module2.ts without noticing it... Thanks for the time and sorry for the inconvenience...

After moving it to Module1.ts, it is working perfectly.

Maybe that's why it is not suggested to stay up late to write code...